# In python, what happens if we have a function with same name as the one we have imported. Which one will run?

Tags: python, function, oop

In a python program, if we have a locally defined function, and another one we have imported from some other module. Which one will run ?

```
from example.maths import multiply

def multiply(a,b):
    -----

multiply(2,3)
```

Also, if I want to write a function in cython and import it. And, at the same time, retain locally defined function in case user doesn't have cython installed. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: @PrakharPratyush You need to put some effort into your question. See [ask].

Comment: The hover-text for the downvote button begins, "This question does not show any research effort...".

Answer (score 0):

If you have two names the same, the newer one passed by runtime is remained. Since you wanted to not override the multiply you imported, you can use `import...as` statement and give that multiply a different name. Also, cython is basically the same upon import.

```
from example.maths import multiply as multi

def multiply(a,b):
    -----

multiply(2,3)
# multi(2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not considered a good coding practice. You should never define function with the same name as imported function.

In your case, the function You defined locally will have precedence over imported function. Think it this way: if You have some variable that is defined in `__main__` part of code, and then You use same name for some variable in some function, that variable will "override" first one. Same happens with imports.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. 
If you call multiply after you define a new function, you will call the locally defined function. If you call multiply before, you will work with the imported function.

A short example in Python 3:

```
import math
print(math)
# <module 'math' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/math.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>

def math():
   pass

print(math)
# <function math at 0x7fe5a376db70>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In a python program, if we have a locally defined function, and another one we have imported from some other module. Which one will run ?

Yours will replace the previous one, and I believe any IDE will give you a warning on that.

You can use built-in function [globals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) to see all available global symbols in the current module at the point where it's called:

```
from math import floor

print(globals())

def floor(x):
    print 'hello, ' + x

print(globals())
```

The first `print(globals())` will print:

`{'floor': <built-in function floor>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'test.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}`

But the second one will print:

`{'floor': <function floor at 0x104649cf8>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'test.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}`

You can see the symbol `floor` has been replaced by the later one.

> Also, if I want to write a function in cython and import it. And, at the same time, retain locally defined function in case user doesn't have cython installed. How can this be achieved?

You can use the following way to achieve it:

```
try:
    from your_module import func_maybe_not_exist
except ImportError:
    def func_maybe_not_exist():
        print "local implementation"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_maybe_not_exist()
```